# GetStringAsync method in HttpClient throw an exception in WP8

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8, windows-phone, httpclient

Recently, I develop an App for WP8 and at the begining all worked OK. However, since yesterday nigth I was getting an error when trying to retrieve the *RSS data* from an url.

This is part of the code I use to get the data:

```
try
{
   HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
   var result = await client.GetStringAsync("http://www.scoop.it/t/recycling-by-miguel18/rss.xml");
   var parseResult = XDocument.Parse(result);
   . . .
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
   throw new Exception("Error: " + ex.Message);
}
```

Where source is the string which contain the url to get the *RSS data*.
As commented, at the begining it was working OK, I was able to get the data in work with it.

Now, it raise the following error:
**Response status code does not indicate success: 404 ().**

If I put the url directly to any browser I can see the *RSS feeds*. So, I don't undertand what would be wrong with the code. I am a little lost.

If you can help me to figure out what is wrong that would be very helpful

Regards!

Comment: How do you expect us to help you? You only posted a generic two lines of code.

Comment: Hi I4V. I have updated the code. Basically, at the moment to use the following: await client.GetStringAsync, is where I'm getting the error.

Comment: Mike, Your code worked for me. You may be blocked by that site.

Comment: are you running this on the device or in the emulator?

Comment: I'm getting the same error with that method in another web, but i'm not blocked because it's the first time i'm accessing it... any sugestions?

Comment: @MikePR I had the same issue on the device but on the emulator everything works fine. Have you sorted it?

Answer (score 2):

You need provide access to internet for your WP emulator.

This article can be helpful

[connect WP emulator to internet](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/wsdevsol/archive/2013/10/01/why-can-t-the-windows-phone-emulator-go-online.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

hmm... I also get same error... using own class to call API, first call on navigatedTo success, second call using button click error, both using same code. On chrome rest client, the url success.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try adding an user-agent header?
See [DownloadString returns a 404 Error: Site needs a User-Agent Header](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23001265/downloadstring-returns-a-404-error-site-needs-a-user-agent-header).

Most webs blocks certain request to avoid robots. Try it and tell me please...