# DownloadString returns a 404 Error: Site needs a User-Agent Header

Tags: c#, .net, http-headers

I have a C# program which worked fine until a day or two ago.  I use the following snippet to grab a page:

```
string strSiteListPath = @"http://www.ngs.noaa.gov/CORS/dates_sites.txt";
Uri uriSiteListPath = new Uri(strSiteListPath);
System.Net.WebClient oWebClient = new System.Net.WebClient();
strStationList = oWebClient.DownloadString(uriSiteListPath);
```

But it consistently returns a 404 Not Found error.  That page completely exists, you are welcome to try it yourself.  Because it worked days ago, and nothing in my code changed, I am given to think maybe the web-server changed in some way.  That's fine, it'll happen, but what exactly has happened here?

Why can I browse to the file manually, but DownloadString fails to get the file?

EDIT:

For completeness, the code now looks like:

```
string strSiteListPath = @"http://www.ngs.noaa.gov/CORS/dates_sites.txt";
Uri uriSiteListPath = new Uri(strSiteListPath);

System.Net.WebClient oWebClient = new System.Net.WebClient();
oWebClient.Headers.Add("User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64; rv:25.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/25.0");

strStationList = oWebClient.DownloadString(uriSiteListPath);
```

Thanks again, Thomas Levesque!

Comment: Well, the url in question returns a 200 Ok for me, followed by 304 NotModified. Are you testing the connection to that url from your desktop or the machine the app is deployed on (if different)? Are there any proxies between the app and the internet? Make sure the http request you're testing with is as close as possible to the one .Net is doing (same user-agent, accept, etc.)

Comment: Try running Fiddler to see what the raw request/responses look like - you should know more after that.

Comment: I have tested both things on 4 different computers.  No proxies are present.

Comment: The request returns 200 OK, but the response body contains a page titled "404 Error"...

Comment: Perhaps the site is trying to block bots and only accepts a real browser User-Agent *EDIT: bingo!*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apparently the site requires that you have a valid `User-Agent` header. If you set that header to something like that:

```
Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64; rv:25.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/25.0
```

Then the request works fine.