# HttpClient not reaching url

Tags: c#, rest, web, windows-phone-8

I'm writing a WP8.1 app that reads and sends data through REST API.
All of them work without problems excepts the "search" one.

This API works in POST and I need to send a string in Json format defining my query. If I set only few filters, the REST API takes too long to respond. Therefore the HttpResponseMessage object has no success code and it returns a "NotFound" message, even if the web API is correcly runnning.

If I try the same request via Postman it works correctly, but if I try it via SoapUi I get a "java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Read timed out" error message.

In SoapUi I managed to extend timeout in order to get a response, but my C# code keeps on not working even if I set the TimeOut property to HttpClient object.

Can someone please help me to resolve my problem?
Thanks!

**EDIT**
The code is really simple:

```
HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
client.BaseAddress = new Uri(baseAddress);
client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
client.DefaultRequestHeaders.ExpectContinue = false;
client.Timeout = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(300);

HttpContent content = new StringContent(json, Encoding.Unicode, "application/json");
HttpResponseMessage response = await client.PostAsync(uri, content));

if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
{
    string jsonResponse = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
}
```

Comment: you need to provide more details about what are you doing (piece of code for example) or else it will be dificult to know what could be the problem

Comment: @ElmerDantas code added

Comment: try using `new StringContent(json.ToString(), Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");`..try also using just `client.BaseAddress = new Uri(baseAddress)` and `client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));` properties.

Comment: The code as I posted it is a result of some tests: starting code was the same you suggested, with Encoding.UTF8 and without ExpectContinue properties.

Comment: I see... I noticed another thing...in your `PostAsync` you're using `uri` wouldn't it be `baseAddress` (or a correct `url`)?

Comment: baseAddress is the address of main REST Api, while uri is the method getting called

Comment: that's what I want to know: this `URI` has the right value? the value should be an valid address or else you will not be able to reach the endpoint

Comment: It is correct: the method is used by several other methods and this is the only one with problems. Even if I change the json to pass the response is correct. Only if the REST Api takes longer than a minute to respond it returns NotFound.

Comment: Oh...sorry! I'm run out of ideas that could help you. I can find anything wrong with this call. I found [this topic](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18432133/getstringasync-method-in-httpclient-throw-an-exception-in-wp8?rq=1) and maybe worth take a look on it

Comment: Unfortunately no luck with this topic

Answer (score 1):

I know that this may won't like you, but have you tried with [RestSharp](http://restsharp.org/)? For some reason in this particular scenario when I need to send information via POST, HTTPClient doesn't work as expected and the "content" information it's set as part of the uri instead of the body.

The equivalente block of code might be like this:

```
var client = new RestClient("http://example.com");
var request = new RestRequest("resource/{id}", Method.POST);
request.AddParameter("name", "value"); 

// execute the request
IRestResponse response = client.Execute(request);

client.ExecuteAsync(request, response => {
     Console.WriteLine(response.Content);
});
```

Comment: I got an error trying to install RestSharp on my project, same error as here: [link](https://github.com/restsharp/RestSharp/issues/808)

Comment: you have to install this library : RestSharp.Portable HttpClient from this link : nuget.org/packages/FubarCoder.RestSharp.Portable

Comment: I just had an issue where HttpClient didn't throw an error, didn't have an error status code but just didn't make it to the correctly setup route like it ate the call and silently failed.  Switched to RestSharp, worked like a charm. +1